# local package cache for arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I am running an arch linux system and want to host a few arch linux VMs.

For installing and updating the VMs they need access to the arch package repository which is usually achieved by a direct network connection to the official arch servers.

In my situation this would result in downloading the same packages again and again for my host and all the VMs.

Is there a good way to cache those packages locally to avoid downloading them again?

Comment: You could create your own local package repository, modelled on how your distribution does it. I don't use Arch, so can't offer any details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a local repository is definitely a good option, but there is a tool made almost exactly for this scenario that you may want to contemplate using.

The tool in question, [`pacserve`](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=117094), was created specifically to allow sharing packages downloaded to one Arch rig with others on the same network to speed up the transfer and cut-down on bandwidth usage (I imagine getting it to work with VMs shouldn't be that difficult). It is in the [ALUR](https://aur.archlinux.org) along with one other dependency that is not in the official repos. Give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

There're many ways to do it.

One simple solution is create a NFS server and mount them on all your client VMs, so they fetch both package files and the package database files from the exported NFS directory.

See [the official wiki for instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/local_repository)

Comment: What is this `alsync` they are talking about? I couldn't [find](https://www.archlinux.de/?page=Packages&repository=&architecture=x86_64&group=&search=alsync&searchfield=file&packager=0) any command like that.

Comment: What file does this serverip/network configuration refer to?